# Validation problem when adding PartialView dinamically in ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[Validation is shown in last contact, eventhough it's correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAHcI.png)

I'm facing this problem right here. I have a _ContactsPartial and when called, it add fields to input contact data dinamically to the Create view of the Patient. It's all fine when only one contact is shown, but when trying to add more than one it validates every field, even if the last one is correct.

Here is the PartialView:

```
@model Vital365.Models.ContactModel
<div class="d-flex mb-2">
    <div class="me-2">
        <label for="Ddd">DDD</label>
        <input id="dddInput" type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Ddd">
        <span asp-validation-for="Ddd" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="me-2">
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Número</label>
        <input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="PhoneNumber">
        <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ContactName">Nome</label>
        <input id="contactNameInput" class="form-control" asp-for="ContactName">
        <span asp-validation-for="ContactName" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="deleteContact" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ms-2 mt-4"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it's called using ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addPhoneContact', function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Patient/DisplayNewContact',
    success: function (partialView) {
        $('.ContactsFieldClass').append(partialView);
    }
   });
});
```

Any ideas on how to control the validation to only appear on really invalid fields?

Answer (score 0):

-> Firstly,You have including scripts for client-side validation in your layout.

Code:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
 validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation- 
 unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

-> then update your PartialView, Follow my code:-

```
@model Vital365.Models.ContactModel

@{
 var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Generate a unique ID for 
 each instance of the partial view
 }

 <div class="d-flex mb-2">
 <div class="me-2">
    <label for="@($"Ddd_{uniqueId}")">DDD</label>
    <input id="@($"dddInput_{uniqueId}")" name="@($"Ddd_{uniqueId}")" 
     type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Ddd">
    <span asp-validation-for="Ddd" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
  <div class="me-2">
    <label for="@($"PhoneNumber_{uniqueId}")">Número</label>
    <input id="@($"phoneNumberInput_{uniqueId}")" 
  name="@($"PhoneNumber_{uniqueId}")" type="number" class="form-control" 
  asp-for="PhoneNumber">
    <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
 <div>
    <label for="@($"ContactName_{uniqueId}")">Nome</label>
    <input id="@($"contactNameInput_{uniqueId}")" 
 name="@($"ContactName_{uniqueId}")" class="form-control" asp- 
 for="ContactName">
    <span asp-validation-for="ContactName" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ms-2 mt-4 deleteContact"> 
     <i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
</div>
```

-> Ajax code:-

```
$(document).on('click', '#addPhoneContact', function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Patient/DisplayNewContact',
    success: function (partialView) {
        $('.ContactsFieldClass').append(partialView);
         var form = $('form'); // Assuming your form has only one form 
                             //element, adjust selector accordingly if not
        form.removeData('validator');
        form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    }
 });
});
```